# Xamarin skiasharp canvas in carousel won't refresh.

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, canvas, skiasharp

Canvas refreshes only on resize of window. What happens when I resize window and how can I simulate it to update canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [InvalidateSurface](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasView.InvalidateSurface()/) method on your canvas when you want to force the redraw. Remember to do it on the main thread (if you're not already on it):

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  canvas.InvalidateSurface();
});
```

Comment: Actually I need to redraw a line. It redraws only when size of window changes (Paint_Surface being called)

Comment: and when do you want to do it? on which event of which control?

Comment: I want to do it on CarouselPage CurrentPageChanged event